# Converting Data From Serial Port to Display as Decimal in Python

Tags: python

I am starting a program that reads data from a radio receiver.  The data is 6 bytes long and updates every 1 second.  The program reads the serial port USB data, but the data is in some format that does not display correctly.  What I do know is that it should be in an unsigned integer.

Each data string comes in as 6 bytes and each byte represents a number corresponds to the data the receiver has logged.

```
import serial
t = 0
while t == 0:
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART', 9600, bytesize=8, stopbits=1,      timeout=None, xonxoff=0, rtscts=0, dsrdtr=0)
s=ser.readline(6)
#s=ser.read(6)
print("Streams received during interval: ")
print (s)

print("__________")
end
```

I am expecting an output that looks like:

> 0 101 0 0 91 145

but what I am getting is:

> eV�

I think there is something off in the data coming in and how it prints in the print statement.  I just need to make sure the data is coming in correctly before I move on.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are converting bytes to a string with your `'%s' % s` statement. It's showing up as whatever random ASCII character corresponds to your bytes.

Instead, try printing the bytes as integers:

```
print ' '.join([ord(ss) for ss in s])
```

Comment: I get this back when I print now
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: Try just `print s`, or `print map(int, s)`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out and thought I would post my solution for the problem.  Using NumPy I was able to easily output the correct data.  I am working with a Dorji DRF4432S receiver and a Dorji DRF5150S transmitter.  These are setup to send analog voltages from a sensor that basically outputs nothing until it is triggered, the the voltages with remain high for a few seconds then return to the zero value.  Hopefully this might help someone looking for coding help with this sensor.

```
import serial
import numpy as np

t = 0
while t == 0:
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART', 9600, bytesize=8, stopbits=1,  timeout=None, xonxoff=0, rtscts=0, dsrdtr=0)
s=ser.readline(6)
#s=ser.read(6)
print("Streams received during interval: ")

ss=np.fromstring(s, dtype=np.uint8, count=6)
sen_1_group=ss[0]
sen_1_id=ss[1]
sen_1_voltage=ss[2]+ss[3]
sen_1_battery=ss[4]
sen_1_signal=ss[5]

print (ss)
print "Group Id = ", sen_1_group , "Sensor ID = ", sen_1_id
print "Sensor ", sen_1_id, " Voltage = ", sen_1_voltage
print "Sensor ", sen_1_id, " Battery = ", sen_1_battery
print "Sensor ", sen_1_id, " Signal Strength = ", sen_1_signal

print("__________")
end
```

This resulted in the data coming out correctly as can be seen below:

```
>> Streams received during interval: 
>>[  0 101   0   0  84 169]
>>Group Id =  0 Sensor ID =  101
>>Sensor  101  Voltage =  0
>>Sensor  101  Battery =  84
>>Sensor  101  Signal Strength =  169
>>__________
```